# Access VBA programmatically setting font/size not working

Tags: ms-access, fonts, vba

I have a button that is supposed to change the font face and size of a textbox to Tahoma 8pt. The button event is:

```
Private Sub btnSetFont_Click()
    MsgBox ("Setting Inventory Description to Tahoma 8pt")
    Me.InventoryDescription.FontSize = 8
    Me.InventoryDescription.FontName = "Tahoma"
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the text does not change. I'm testing it by first editing the font and size by hand, and then pressing my button.

However, if I do the following,

```
Private Sub btnSetFont_Click()
    MsgBox ("Setting Inventory Description to Tahoma 8pt")
    Me.InventoryDescription.Value = "hello"
    Me.InventoryDescription.FontSize = 24
    Me.InventoryDescription.FontName = "Times"
End Sub
```

The text changes to "hello" of course, but the font and size do indeed change. (I used Times 24pt because the default for the textbox is Tahoma 8pt and I wanted to make sure it wasn't just reverting to the default) This made me think that the textbox needs to have the focus to make the changes. So, I tried:

```
Private Sub btnSetFont_Click()
    MsgBox ("Setting Inventory Description to Tahoma 8pt")
    Me.InventoryDescription.SetFocus
    Me.InventoryDescription.FontSize = 24
    Me.InventoryDescription.FontName = "Times"
End Sub
```

But, no go.

Soooo, what am I doing wrong?

---

I found one aspect to the problem. The text box .TextFormat is set to Rich Text. If I change it to Plain Text, then the button effect works. However, the reason it is set to Rich Text is to allow italics. So, I tried first setting it to plain text, and then changing the font/size, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You say it does work when you change the value, why not try `Me.InventoryDescription.Value = Me.InventoryDescription.Value`?

Comment: Interesting. I had already tried that (except using a dummy variable) and no go. And the direct method doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need: I want the users to be able to format the text with boldface, italics and underlined characters, but I don't want to allow font name changes, or font size changes. And copy/paste actions often import formatted text in my textBox, which needs to be "cleaned".

The solution I found is in the Function below.
This function should be called by an Event Procedure (i.e. After Update, or On Click).

---

```
Public Function CleanRichText(strTEXT, strFont, nSize)
'*****************************************************
' 

    For i = 1 To 9
        strTEXT = Replace(strTEXT, "size=" & i, "size=" & nSize)
    Next i

    strTEXT = Replace(strTEXT, "font face", "font_face")
    strTEXT = Replace(strTEXT, "font" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "face", "font_face")

    Do While InStr(1, strTEXT, "font_face=" & Chr(34)) > 0
        iCut1 = InStr(1, strTEXT, "font_face=" & Chr(34))
        iCut2 = InStr(iCut1 + 12, strTEXT, Chr(34))
        strLeft = Left(strTEXT, iCut1 - 1) & "font_face=Face"
        strRight = Right(strTEXT, Len(strTEXT) - iCut2)
        strTEXT = strLeft & strRight
    Loop

    Do While InStr(1, strTEXT, "font_face=") > 0
        iCut1 = InStr(1, strTEXT, "font_face=")
        iCut2 = InStr(iCut1 + 12, strTEXT, Chr(32))
        strLeft = Left(strTEXT, iCut1 - 1) & "font face=" & strFont & Chr(32)
        strRight = Right(strTEXT, Len(strTEXT) - iCut2)
        strTEXT = strLeft & strRight
    Loop
    CleanRichText = strTEXT

End Function
```

---

```
Private Sub Cause_AfterUpdate()

    Me.Cause = CleanRichText(Me.Cause, Me.Cause.FontName, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Try adding `Me.Repaint` after changing the font.

Comment: Hmm. That didn't help. I'm still in Access 2010.

Comment: You say Times works, but not Tohoma? Are you sure you have Tohoma installed?

Comment: The font property for the textbox is Tahoma 8pt. If I open the form and start typeing, it is in Tahoma 8pt. Sometimes I want to cut and paste from another source, so I want to be able to set the font back to Tahoma. However, I do want font editing ability only so I can have bold and italic. It is a form for library use. Also, if I use Tahoma 8pt instead of Times 24pt, when I change the text to "hello", I get Tahoma 8pt. I used a different font to make sure I was actually setting it, not having it revert to the default. Kind of a lot to explain I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: Does that mean that the font/size changes for you? I have my text box set to Rich Text. When I open the form, I type something in the text box, select it, and set the font/size. Then I'm pressing the button. Is that what you are doing and the formatting changes?

Comment: Golly. That's weird. Doesn't work for me on two different computers. Could you try this: after you change the format with the button, change the format with the Access ribbon menu. Then try the button again. Tell me if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me using Access 2010.

I added this code to the click event for a couple command buttons that allow the user to dynamically control the font size in a **List box** called teachersList.

```
Private Sub cmdDecreaseFont_Click()
     Me.teachersList.FontSize = Me.teachersList.FontSize - 1
End Sub

Private Sub cmdIncreaseFont_Click()
    Me.teachersList.FontSize = Me.teachersList.FontSize + 1
End Sub
```

Then added a couple simple command buttons to the form
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I started using the @yves solution but it fails when a "font" tag includes a "size" property, for example:

```
<font face="Arial" size="5">a colour in it will break?</font>
```

So I found a better way using #RegExp, you can follow the thread in this forum: [accessforums.net](https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=75156)

```
Public Function CleanRichTextRegEx(ByVal strText As String, _
                               ByVal strFont As String, _
                               ByVal nSize As Integer) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    On Error Resume Next
    With objRegEx
       .Global = True
       'Replace font size
       .Pattern = "size=[0-9]"
       strText = .Replace(strText, " size=" & nSize)
       'Replace font face
       .Pattern = "face=([""'])(?:[\r\n]*(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"
       strText = .Replace(strText, "face=" & strFont)
    End With
    Set objRegEx = Nothing
    CleanRichTextRegEx = strText
End Function
```

And you can use it in this way:

```
richText = "<font face='Arial' size='5'>a colour in it will break?</font>" 
richTextResult = CleanRichTextRegEx(richText, "Arial", 2)
```