# Access-VBA Changing Font and Size of text in form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to change the font and font size of the text in one box of my form

```
With Me.[Notes:]
.SetFocus
.FontName = "Verdana"
.FontSize = 8
.ForeColor = vbBlack
End With
```

I have already looked here

[Access VBA programmatically setting font/size not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455028/access-vba-programmatically-setting-font-size-not-working)

And seem to have that working, though I still have a couple of issues.

1. It changes the text in the right box but on EVERY one of my records, rather than just the one I'm editing.
2. It only works on text which has been types into the text box directly. Not on text that has been pasted into the form. (This is the reason for the button in the first place)

In case it matters, I'm using MS Access 2016

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: Is this a continuous form/subform? or a datasheet - or a regular form?

Comment: I believe it is a "TextBox" within a "Section"

Comment: That's by design. A control appears the same on all records in continous view.

Comment: Are you trying to change the formatting based on a value? Nothing in your question seems to indicate why you're changing the font but if that's the case, then conditional formatting might work for you.

Comment: Ah, the reason for the formatting is that in writing our client reports we often copy/paste text from other sources, typically emails and we'd like for a simpler way of having the report be consistent in its formatting

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a continuous form, sounds like you need to add an IF statement to specify under which conditions this should take place.  Then place it on the current event of the form.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()    
if condition met then 
    With Me.[Notes:]
    .SetFocus
    .FontName = "Verdana"
    .FontSize = 8
    .ForeColor = vbBlack
    End With
    end if 
end sub
```

For the second issue you can set the code (or create a procedure and call it) on the afterupdate event of the field

```
Private Sub notes_AfterUpdate()
if condition met then 
    With Me.[Notes:]
    .SetFocus
    .FontName = "Verdana"
    .FontSize = 8
    .ForeColor = vbBlack
    End With
    end if 
End Sub
```

Comment: this sounds god and i will test it when i'm at work next, but what would i use for a condition to select just THIS form?

Comment: When do you want this change in font and size to appear?

Comment: either when leaving the text field or when pressing a button (working on the leaving text field right now)

Comment: That's already happening on the after update event on the textbox. If there is no other criteria, then forget the if statement. You just have to set the font color and size back to what it originally was on the current event of the form.  Maybe if I understood the purpose for your doing this, I could help more.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had mentioned it in my original post. The purpose is so that when pasting text into the form from elsewhere, such as outlook, all the text will be formatted the same way

Comment: I've made a few changes, based on your advice and this is the current code

`Private Sub Notes__AfterUpdate()
    With Me.Notes_
    .FontName = "Verdana"
    .FontSize = 8
    End With
End Sub` There is however, still the problem that it does nothing to text that was not originally typed into the form